# How to implement editable colors in wpf application?

Tags: wpf

In application i have usercontrol with datagrid in it. For some columns i set special foreground `Foreground={DynamicResource SomeForegroundBrush}`. Upper of VisualTree in resources i creating brush: `<SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeForegroundBrush" Color="{Binding ColorSettings.SomeForegroundColor}"/>`.

In editor window i just editing ColorSettings object.

The problem is that i setting default colors in ColorSettings object, but now i have different themes for multiple build configurations, so default color should depend on theme.

What can i do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to have to find a way of changing your application based on build settings. You could for example specify this color in an external resource dictionary (xaml file), then have two different versions of this file. Your build can then 'pick' which resource file to use.